# Show Reports Teleriks in asp mvc project fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, reportviewer

Good afternoon, I have a project in asp mvc 5 with razor views, which I am trying to show teleriks some reports that I have made, and are in the Content folder, yet is giving me a lot of problems and errors.

Like this: Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version = 7.0.13.220, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = a9d7983dfcc261be' or one of Its dependencies. The system can not find the file specified.

[image]

I've been trying to follow the steps in this tutorial

http://www.telerik.com/blogs/telerik-reporting-in-mvc-sure-it-takes-8-quick-steps-

Here is my web.config, on the part of handlers

```
<system.webServer> <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" /> <handlers> <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" /> <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" /> <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" /> <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" /> <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" /> <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" /> <remove name="Telerik.ReportViewer.axd_*"/> <add name="Telerik.ReportViewer.axd_*" path="Telerik.ReportViewer.axd" verb="*" type ="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.HttpHandler, Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=7.0.13.220, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" preCondition="integratedMode"/> </handlers> </system.webServer>
```

And part of the view I have been trying unsuccessfully to set up (I added at the root of the project, a webform asp, aspx to work with)

```
<%@ Import Namespace="SSMS_2._0._1.Content" %> <%@ Register assembly="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=7.0.13.220, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" namespace="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms" tagprefix="telerik" %> <%@ Register assembly="Telerik.Reporting, Version=7.0.13.220, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" namespace="Telerik.Reporting" tagprefix="telerik" %> <form id="main" method="post" action=""> <telerik:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" Width="100%" Height="800px" runat="server"> </telerik:ReportViewer> </form> <script runat="server"> public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control) { // to avoid the server form (<form runat="server"> requirement } protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) { base.OnLoad(e); var instanceReportSource = new Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource(); instanceReportSource.ReportDocument = new Dashboard(); ReportViewer1.ReportSource = instanceReportSource; } </script>
```

I came up here and took days looking for the solution, any help would be welcome, thanks

Comment: You many need to install the telerik reporting see if this helps http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/installation-installing-from-msi

Comment: Is already installed @mike123

Comment: not sure if this might be the case but sometimes versions don't match

Answer (score 0):

What to do, was to update the project with teleriks tools, which sent all the necessary resources for the reportviewer will see, however, now have problems with parameters, here's another question to close this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36538991/how-to-add-parameters-to-a-reportviewer-telerik-by-code-because-the-wizard-does